# What does おらん mean?

Tags: meaning, dialects

> お前の右に出るものは一人としておらん。

What does おらん mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it means いない （as おる means いる） in the nagoya dialect.

Comment: I do not think it is the nagoya dialect but standard. It slightly sounds old, arrogant and from a dialect.
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/34019/m0u/
I agree with the meaning.

Comment: To me (resident in eastern Japan), it's dialectal. Being old doesn't mean being standard because Classical Japanese is an ancestor of western dialects.

Comment: It's the Kansai/Osaka dialect. Here it's colloquial and used mostly by young/"cool" people.